# Vite.js - How do I enable full page reload on Ctrl+S?

Tags: vite

If im running vite dev server with "npm run dev" and I edit say utils.js, how do I make vite do a FULL reload from index.html so ALL the scripts gets reloaded?

The problem I have is: if I edit any files (and save, ctrl+s) except for index.html the vite server will reload once BUT my index.js will invoke twice? is this a vite.js bug?

Answer (score 11):

You have to configure a custom `handleHotUpdate` hook in `vite.config.ts` or `vite.config.js` (TypeScript/JavaScript)

[handleHotUpdate documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#handlehotupdate)

The code below is adapted from an answer to this issue on GitHub: [Option to force full reload on change, disabling HMR.](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9743#issuecomment-1221292059)

**vite.config.ts:**

```js
import { defineConfig, PluginOption } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

const fullReloadAlways: PluginOption = {
  name: 'full-reload-always',
  handleHotUpdate({ server }) {
    server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload" })
    return []
  },
} as PluginOption

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), fullReloadAlways],
})
```

**vite.config.js:**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

const fullReloadAlways = {
  name: 'full-reload-always',
  handleHotUpdate({ server }) {
    server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload" })
    return []
  },
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), fullReloadAlways],
})
```